# Основы Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Начинаю разбираться с Firebase Database, пробую сделать базовое социальное приложение. Хочу реализовать поиск по имени. Так вот у меня вопрос. Как достать UID, зная только никнейм.

```
"users"
       "uid"
             "name"
             "email"
             "nickname"
             "uid"
```

Я хочу ввести nickname пользователя в поле и после этого показать его профиль, так вот, как мне через никнейм узнать uid?

Comment: Если ты только начал и нет принципиальной разницы, то используй firestore - это что вроде работы над ошибками касательно Realtime database. Там можно создавать запросы и искать по определенному полю.

Comment: Спасибо, начал разбираться с Cloud Firestore, он действительно удобнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присоединяюсь к **Valera Kvip**, используйте [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query). Устаревший Firebase Database лучше не использовать, он реально запутанный и неудобный.

А поиск можно сделать например вот так:

```
db.collection("users").whereField("nickname", isEqualTo: "Nick").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print(document.documentID)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, начал разбираться с Cloud Firestore, он действительно удобнее

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, **Firebase Database** - не очень гибкая система и Вам придется пройтись циклом по всем данным из ветки users, проверить, соответствует ли имя тому, что вам нужно и тогда из этого же блока получить нужный **id**.